# Deep learning with python (Cosine similarity)

Tags: python, deep-learning, cosine-similarity

I am learning how to use VGG16 model to recognize  similar objects. I created a folder "images" can put some `.jpg` inside the folder.

But i am confuse with the cosine_similarity part of the program.
The cosine_similarity function is to convert all jpg in "images" folder to Eigenvector and compare to each others. They are more similar when the value tends to be 1.

But I don't understand in below code,

`sim = ratings.dot(ratings.T)`

Why the jpg is comparing to itself (in transpose) but not others?

Could anyone explain to me regarding the cosine_similarity below?

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
import os
import sys

#Calculate similar matrics
def cosine_similarity(ratings):
    sim = ratings.dot(ratings.T)
    if not isinstance(sim,np.ndarray):
        sim = sim.toarray()
    norms = np.array([np.sqrt(np.diagonal(sim))])
    return (sim/norms/norms.T)


def main():
    #from "folder-->image" find all of JPEG files
    y_test=[]
    x_test=[]
    for img_path in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\ML\\CNN model\\VGG16\\images"):
        if img_path.endswith(".jpg"):
            img = image.load_img("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\ML\\CNN model\\VGG16\\images\\" + img_path, target_size=(224,224))
            y_test.append(img_path[0:4])
            x = image.img_to_array(img)
            x= np.expand_dims(x,axis=0)
            if len(x_test) > 0:
                x_test = np.concatenate((x_test,x))
            else:
                x_test = x

    #Convert to VGG input format 
    x_test = preprocess_input(x_test)

    #include_top=False == not getting VGG16 last 3 layers
    model = VGG16(weights = "imagenet", include_top=False)

    #Get features
    features = model.predict(x_test)

    #Calculate similar metrics
    features_compress = features.reshape(len(y_test), 7*7*512)
    sim = cosine_similarity(features_compress)

    #
    inputNo = int(sys.argv[1])

    top = np.argsort(-sim[inputNo], axis=0)[1:3]

    #get the first 2 most similar index
    recommend = [y_test[i] for i in top]
    print(recommend)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is jpg is comparing to itself (in transpose) but not others?

`sim = cosine_similarity(features_compress)`

So here, I reckon `features_compress` is the set of features for all your images that are contained within x_test, and not a single image.

Because in the for loop earlier, that's what you seem to be doing with `np.concatenate()`.

And if that indeed is the case, then think of the result returned from `cosine_similarity()` as a matrix that tells you the similarity of each image with every other image.

Comment: You are correct. features_compress is the set of features for all your images that are contained within x_test, and not a single image.

Comment: I'm wondering why `cosine_similarity()` can tell the similarity of each image with every other image. 
The cosine similarity tells us a similarity value between 2 vectors. 
But in this case `ratings.dot(ratings.T)` --> Isn't it refer to dot product of matrix "rating" and transpose matrix "rating"? I just can't get the role of transpose.

Comment: @kelvin.aaa2 Yes, that is correct, the cosine similarity does indeed give you the similarity between vectors. Now in this case, you've got a matrix `rating`, which contains all the vectors that we're interested in. When you transpose this matrix and take the dot product, you're effectively multiplying every vector with every other vector. For instance, the entry 1,1 in the resulting matrix is similarity between the first vector and itself. The entry 4,5 is the similarity between the 4th vector and the 5th vector. And so on.

Comment: I also suggest taking an actual matrix and trying it yourself by hand. Take a 4x3 matrix, take its transpose(Otherwise you can't really multiply it because the dimensions won't match), and take the dot between the two. You get a 4x4 matrix and observer the results carefully. The diagonal elements will be the similarities between every vector with itself, ie the entries (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) and (4,4). Another thing you should notice is that entries (1,2) and (2,1) will be same because the similarity of 2nd vector with 1st and 1st vector with 2nd are the same.. So that's the basic idea here

Comment: I pressed the up-vote button. So sorry, I guess that was my mistake.

Comment: @kelvin.aaa2 no problem, you can also undo the down-vote by pressing on the up-vote button, if you like :)

Comment: I think I have already done that. The system just reply with
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."